# Assign aliased variables to new object

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2017, ecmascript-2018

How can we assign aliased keys to a new object like

```
var obj1 = { c: 1 }; var obj2= ({ f: c } = obj1 ); console.log(obj2);

OR

var obj1 = { c: 1 }; var obj2= { f: c } = obj1 ; console.log(obj2);
```

is returning `{c: 1}` instead of `{f: 1}`.

How can to achieve this?

I don't want to do this like

var obj1 = { c: 1 }; var { f: c } = obj1 ; const obj2 = {f}; console.log(obj2);

Comment: What is `a` and `c`?

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal By mistake. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Assignment is simpler than destructuring in this case:

```js
var obj1 = { c: 1 }; 

var obj2= { f: obj1.c }; 

console.log(obj2);
```

And if you really must use destructuring you can use an IIFE:

```js
var obj1 = { c: 1 }; 

var obj2= (({ c: f }) => ({ f }))(obj1); 

console.log(obj2);
```